# Properly joining tables in Rails using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My models:
    models/organization.rb

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_payments
end

models/organization_payment.rb

class OrganizationPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

The organizations table has in it the following columns:

```
id
org_name
```

The organization_payments has in it the following columns:

```
organization_id
amount
```

When I do:

```
@organization_payments = OrganizationPayment.joins(:organization)
.where("organization_payments.organization_id = organizations.id")
```

I only get the columns from the organization_payments table, not the org_name column from the organizations table. What's the correct syntax for the joins statement?

## Caveat:

Note that if both tables have an id column (and they should), you need to be specific on which one gets included, else you will end up with incorrect links in the Index view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use `select`, like this:

```
@organization_payments = OrganizationPaiment.select('*, organizations.org_name as organization_name').joins(:organization)
```

this way, `org_name` value will be accessible like this:

```
organization_payment.organization_name
```

The more "Rails" way to get the same goal is to pre-load associated organizations with `includes`:

```
@organization_payments = OrganizationPayment.includes(:organization)
```

and simply use `ActiveRecord` association, like this:

```
organization_payment.organization.org_name
```

Comment: The first one (non-Rails way) worked but the rails way did not work.

Comment: Marek Lipka: no error, but org_name is not there, only the information from the organization_payments table

Comment: Here's a little side issues I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001027/using-joins-with-will-paginate-in-rails-4

Answer (score 3):

Marek Lipka's answer is good, but I'd also suggest you look at delegate. If you modify OrganizationPayment to this:

```
class OrganizationPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  delegate :org_name to: :organization
end
```

You'll then be able to call organization_payment.org_name to retrieve the organization name. If you want to iterate through many OrganizationPayment objects, use *includes* to ensure the delegation doesn't generate a new SQL call for each lookup. So:

```
OrganizationPayment.includes(:organization).each{|payment| puts payment.org_name}
```